# Is it possible to use OUT/INOUT parameter along with return refcursor in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, ref-cursor

Here is an example snippet. I am trying to have a INOUT parameter and also trying to return a refcursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reffunc2(IN key int, INOUT name int) 
RETURNS refcursor 
AS $$
DECLARE
ref refcursor;
BEGIN
name = 123;
OPEN ref FOR SELECT col FROM test;
RETURN ref;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying an `OUT` or `INOUT` parameter is the same as specifying a return value, so the two definitions have to match:

- with a single `OUT` parameter, `RETURNS` must specify the type of that parameter
- with more than one `OUT` parameter, you must use `RETURNS record`

You cannot specify one result column as `OUT` parameter and the other one as result.

Use this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION reffunc2(
   IN key int,
   INOUT name int,
   OUT x refcursor
) RETURNS record
```

In the function body, you must assign values to `name` and `x` and use `RETURN` without argument.